# Why `<C-h>` is mapped to backspace even if I remove all the insert-mode keymaps of `<C-h>`?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, lua

As title. I'm using NeoVim and there is a syntax to remove all mappings of specific key-comb. in specified mode:

```lua
vim.keymap.del('i', '<C-h>')
```

But after the call `:imap <C-h>` shows:

```
i <C-H>    *@<C-R>=AutoPairsDelete()<CR>
```

and if I pressed `<C-h>` in insert-mode it worked as backspace. Any idea?

Comment: While I just found my question answered as per the link I just submitted myself, I still decide not to delete this question since I formulae the title in a more-likely-to-be-searched manner. I think this will help future readers to find the solution more easily.

Comment: That is because `<c-h>` in traditional Unix terminals **is the same as the backspace key**

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Many thanks for sharing the background knowledge!